# Decompose 3x3 Matrix

Tags: c#, matrix

I have a 3x3 matrix I'm using to track movement in 2D. I need to extract from that the translation, rotation and scale matrices. Can anyone suggest how I would do this? I've had no luck searching online so far (possibly I'm using the wrong terms).

Comment: That would be more of a mathematical question than a programming question (since you are looking for an algorithm that will somehow factor out three matrices that have previously been multiplied).  My guess is that it will be something like figuring out what three numbers were multiplied to get 420 (which has 2, 3, 5, and 7 as prime factors).  Good luck.

Comment: So you are rotating the 3D matrix and want to find the difference between original and final?  If matrix are same size, then on each 3D object draw the same line between the same two points.   Then compare the slope of the two lines.

Comment: It's more that I need to programmatically find the translation of a vector from a matrix where I don't know what's been changed in that matrix.

Comment: @djcmm476 When using homogeneous coordinates, the translation vector is the last row (in a row-major matrix) or column (in a column-major matrix). It would be better to keep these things (rotation, scale, translation) separately in their original form and work from that. Floating-point precision errors compound over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just off the top of my head so there may be an error in here, but:

Assuming your matrix is row-major (just transpose everything if you're using column major):

```
|  cos(t)   -sin(t)   0 |
|  sin(t)    cos(t)   0 |
|        tx        ty 1 |
```

The translation vector will be the last row in the matrix `[tx ty 1]`. Extracting scale and rotation in a composed matrix is a bit trickier.

Looking at a 3x3 rotation matrix,

```
| cos(t)  -sin(t) 0 |
| sin(t) cos(t) 0 |
| 0       0      1 |
```

And a scale matrix

```
| vx  0   0 |
| 0   vy  0 |
| 0   0   1 |
```

The combined rotation & scale matrix might look like (ct = cos(t), st = sin(t))

```
|  vx*ct  -vx*st   0 |
|  vy*st  vy*ct   0 |
|      0      0   1 |
```

For uniform scaling, `vx=vy`.

```
|  v*ct  -v*st   0 |
|  v*st  v*ct   0 |
|      0      0   1 |
```

Remembering the trig identity

```
ct^2 + st^2 = 1
```

We can see that the

```
(v*ct)^2 + (v*st)^2 = v^2
```

or

```
v^2*ct^2 + v^2*st^2 = v^2
```

... all the terms of which are in the composite (scale,rotation,translation or SRT for short) matrix,

So,

```
v = sqrt((v*ct)^2 + (v*st)^2)
```

or

```
v = sqrt(M[0,0]^2 + M[0,1]^2);
```

Theta, then is just

```
t = acos(vct/v)
```

or

```
t = acos(M[0,0]/v)
```

or, this might work much easier but I haven't tried it:

```
theta = atan2(vst,vct), 
scale = sqrt(vst^2+vct^2)
```

where `^` is an exponent, not an XOR.

... and you can work out the rest.

It would be wiser to keep your scale, rotation and translation values around and use those values both to build the matrix and for whatever other tasks you require. Relying on the matrix as the only container for that information will eventually lead to compound floating-point errors and other drama.

Some notes:

Theta is an angle. It's a fun, easy-to-draw Greek symbol, and all us engineers love greek characters. It's mostly Stockholm syndrome since some of them look like 5's, and some of them are impossible to draw unless you're Greek.

This works great for 2D, where there is only one possible rotation axis. If you're working in three (or higher! It's a thing now!) dimensions, the concept is the same but the implementation becomes much, much messier.

`st`, `ct`, `vst`, `vct`, etc. are all contained in the composite matrix you have available. (Composite == concatenated == combined. The terminology in use depends on who you're reading.) The non-intuitive part is extracting the elements that you need from the matrix. This requires understanding what is in the matrix, *where*, and **why**.

This is a solvable problem. Normally, I'm a sit-down-and-start-coding kind of guy, and in 25 years of professional development, I'd have to say that it's worked out pretty well so far. But, there are times where a whiteboard or a notebook and a mechanical pencil are better friends than your keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

For a column major matrix, given:

- X vector of < Xx, Xy >;
- Y vector of < Yx, Yy > and
- Translation/position of < Tx, Ty >,

  The corresponding column major transformation matrix is:

[image]

```
The translation is:
```

[image]

```
For the Scaling, the scale factors for the X and Y vectors are:
```

[image]

[image]

The scaling transformation is then:

[image]

```
For Rotation, the normalized vectors are:
```

X Vector: < Xx/Sx, Xy/Sx >

Y Vector: < Yx/Sy, Yy/Sy >

And the rotation transformation "R" is:

[image]

```
RECOMPOSITION:
```

Given translation "T", rotation "R", and scaling "S" transformation in column major order, the original matrix/transform can be recreated with:

```
            T * R * S
```

Assumption, the original transformation has X and Y vectors that are:

- Not parallel;
- Not a length of zero;
- Not mirrored; and
- Not skewed/sheared.

The rotation can be further decomposed into an angle as described by 3Dave (which is row major, and needs to be transposed to be column major).